# Redefine Subscript in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pattern-matching, variable-assignment

I'd like to redefine `Subscript` such that the "binomial tree coordinates" are translated into "flat array coordinates":

```
Unprotect[Subscript];
Subscript[x_, i_, j_] := x[[2 ^ i + j]];
Protect[Subscript];    

(* Binomial Tree *)
y = {.1, {.2, .3}} // Flatten;

Subscript[y, 1, 1]
Subscript[y, 1, 1] = .5;
Subscript[y, 1, 1]
```

What I expect to get is `.3, .5`. Instead I get `Set::write : Tag Subscript in {.1, .2, .3}_1,1 is Protected` and the value is not assigned. Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Mathematica user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the conceptually simplest solution - you add a new "Up" - rule to handle the assignment:

```
Unprotect[Subscript];
Subscript[x_, i_, j_] := x[[2^i + j]]
Set[Subscript[x_, i_, j_], v_] ^:= x[[2^i + j]] = v;
Protect[Subscript];

(*Binomial Tree*)
y = {.1, {.2, .3}} // Flatten

Subscript[y, 1, 1]
Subscript[y, 1, 1] = .5;
Subscript[y, 1, 1]
```

You need a separate rule for handling assignments (`Set`, `=`), otherwise you are attempting to assign to the Subscript expression itself when you do `Subscript[y, 1, 1] = .5`

While the above solution *can* be used literally, it probably should not, since it redefines `Subscript` for all types of the first argument. Such redefinitions may be unsafe - they may clash with other possibly desirable uses of `Subscript`. For example, calling Subscript on some arbitrary symbol x results in an error-message, and evaluation which we may not want:

```
In[137]:= Subscript[x, 1, 2]

During evaluation of In[137]:= Part::partd: Part specification x[[4]] is 
longer than depth  of object.   >>

Out[137]= x[[4]]
```

A safer alternative would be to assign some special head (like a tag) for the binary trees on which you want to redefine `Subscript`, and use patterns to restrict the scope of these redefinitions accordingly. Here is how it might look:

```
Unprotect[btree, Subscript];
ClearAll[btree, Subscript];

Subscript[x_btree, i_, j_] := x[[1, 2^i + j]]

Set[Subscript[x_, i_, j_], v_] ^:= (x[[1, 2^i + j]] = v) /; Head[x] === btree;

Protect[btree, Subscript];
```

You assign you btree structure to the variable like this:

```
In[156]:= y = btree[{.1, .2, .3}]

Out[156]= btree[{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}]
```

Then,

```
In[157]:= Clear[x];
Subscript[y, 1, 1]
Subscript[y, 1, 1] = .5;
Subscript[y, 1, 1]
Subscript[x, 1, 1]

Out[158]= 0.3

Out[160]= 0.5

Out[161]= Subscript[x, 1, 1]
```

In this way, we reduce the possible unwanted effects that such redefinitions can have on some other code (rest of the system).

Looking back at the definition involving `Set`, one thing to note is that we could not have used a simple pattern like `Set[Subscript[x_btree, i_Integer, j_Integer],v_]:=...`, since the variable (`y` here) would not yet evaluate to a value inside `Set` when the pattern is matched, so it won't match.  Using `Condition` (`/;`) is just one way to bring the variable we are assigning to, out of `Set`, and make it evaluate. So, if it is `y`, then `Head[y]` will cause `y` to evaluate - this is the case where we actually want the head of the evaluated expression. In pattern like `x_btree`, we don't give `x` a chance to evaluate before the pattern-matching attempt takes place, and therefore the pattern does not match (since it is still a symbol `y` there).

The additional rule used here is called an `UpValue`. To create such rules, a special syntax is used (`^:=` operator - `UpSetDelayed`, is one way to create `UpValues`). `UpValues` are an important mechanism for "soft" overloading of functions (including system functions), and also creation of custom data types. To  read about them, a good starting point is  [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSetDelayed.html).

Comment: While I started this answer, the majority of the text is Leonid's.